# How to use AWK to filter matrix patterns for user CNs?

Tags: bash, awk

this one was tricky: I have a text file with several user DNs and bellow each one a matrix with the LogonHours pattern (extracted from Active Directory using PowerShell). Looks like this:

```
CN=John Doe,OU=Users,OU=Almox,DC=acme,DC=inc
    Day
    of   --------- Daily  Hours --------
    Week M-3 3-6 6-9 9-N N-3 3-6 6-9 9-M
    Dom  000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000
    Seg  000 000 011 111 111 111 100 000
    Ter  000 000 011 111 111 111 100 000
    Qua  000 000 011 111 111 111 100 000
    Qui  000 000 011 111 111 111 100 000
    Sex  000 000 011 111 111 111 100 000
    Sab  000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000
CN=Jack Dumb,OU=Users,OU=Managers,DC=acme,DC=inc
    All Hours
CN=Barry Foo,OU=Disabled Users,DC=acme,DC=inc
    Day
    of   --------- Daily  Hours --------
    Week M-3 3-6 6-9 9-N N-3 3-6 6-9 9-M
    Dom  000 000 000 000 000 011 111 111
    Seg  111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111
    Ter  111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111
    Qua  111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111
    Qui  111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111
    Sex  111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111
    Sab  111 111 111 111 110 000 000 000
```

How can I extract usernames with an specific LogonHours pattern with AWK?

I was able to count the number of specific patterns using AWK using a "pattern file" as a RS as follows:

```
awk -v RS="$(<patternfile.txt)" '{print RT}' logonhoursCNlist.txt | grep "Week M-3" | wc -l
```

Expected result using a patternfile with the following content...

```
Day
of   --------- Daily  Hours --------
Week M-3 3-6 6-9 9-N N-3 3-6 6-9 9-M
Dom  000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000
Seg  000 000 011 111 111 111 100 000
Ter  000 000 011 111 111 111 100 000
Qua  000 000 011 111 111 111 100 000
Qui  000 000 011 111 111 111 100 000
Sex  000 000 011 111 111 111 100 000
Sab  000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000
```

... is just the usernames on CNs, like this:

```
John Doe
```

Any help I'll appreciate!

Comment: Please post how you were _able to count the number of specific patterns using AWK using a "pattern file" as a RS_?

Comment: @JamesBrown:
awk -v RS="$(<patternfile.txt)" '{print RT}' logonhoursource.txt | grep "Week M-3" | wc -l

The "patternfile.txt" is just the portion in between DNs extracted from logonhoursource.txt.

Comment: I don't see the text `DN` anywhere in your input. Do you mean `CN`? If not, clarify what a `DN` is, don't assume we are famiiiar with your abbreviations. Crucial: [edit] your question to include the expected output given that input.

Comment: @EdMorton, you're rigth... I want the CNs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It'd be something like (untested but will be very close if not exactly what you want):

```
awk -v RS="$(<patternfile.txt)" 'RT!=""{print gensub(/.*CN=([^,]+).*/,"\\1",1)}' logonhoursCNlist.txt
```

The above uses GNU awk for multi-char RS and gensub().

Comment: I just realized this gensub is also returning the very last record on my users list (an user with "All Hours" attribute instead of the reference matrix stored on RS var). Any idea? Regards!

Comment: The RS must not be matching anything. Try printing `RT` to see if it's getting set? Make sure your patternfile is EXACTLY the string you want to match, including all white space and indentation. If it worked for your existing script then it should work for this one though. Actually, I should tweak it to add a test for RT before running the gensub() anyway, I'll do that now.

Comment: damn you're awesome. Thank you very much!